# XML Regex Substitution For Specific Match in Results

Tags: regex, xml, sed, notepad++

I have a xml document with some repeating tags. Simple example goes like:

```
<dog>
  <cat>
...
<dog>
   <cat> 
...
<dog>
   <cat>
```

A sample regex for this example is `<dog>\s+<cat>` which matches each tag combo. That's what I initially want. My question is if I wanted to do substitution (capture group and back reference) but DON'T want to replace each matching pattern with the same value how do I specify? Like in the example above what if I wanted to replace each tag combo with something like:

```
<monkey>
   <cat>
...
<elephant>
   <cat>
...
<lion>
   <cat>
```

I guess in general is there a way to make a substitution non-global? I believe I read that without global substitution it'll only replace the 1st matching pattern. I could use that technique to replace each tag one by one but wanted to know if there was a better solution. The goal is to use the linux sed command but I've been testing in Notepad++.

Comment: please use xml parser like xmlstarlet instead of sed/regex...

Comment: Imagine you have the following input: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<animals>
  <dog>
    <cat>1</cat>
  </dog>
  <dog>
    <cat>2</cat>
  </dog>
  <dog>
    <cat>3</cat>
  </dog>
</animals`

Comment: You can use the following stylesheet: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="animalName" select="animalName"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy></xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//dog[1][./cat]">
        <xsl:element name="{$animalName}"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: After taking a backup of your input file run: `animals=( monkey elephant lion ); for ani in "${animals[@]}"; do java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:animals.xml -xsl:animalsConvertor.xs
lt -o:animals.xml animalName="$ani"; done` 

output: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animals>
   <monkey>
      <cat>1</cat>
   </monkey>
   <elephant>
      <cat>2</cat>
   </elephant>
   <lion>
      <cat>3</cat>
   </lion>
</animals>`

Comment: For more info on `saxon` https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/using-xsl/commandline.html and on XSLT: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_elementref.asp